# Какое из правил применимо к глаголу "(не)доделать" в данном предложении?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

*Лучше доделать, чем не доделать.*

*Лучше доделать, чем недоделать.*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Может, лучше "не( )доделать"? А то со звёздочкой мне кажется не совсем понятным...

Comment: Давай тогда косую нарисуем.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Косой, насколько я понимал всегда, разделяют два полных варианта, так что не знаю... А мой вариант Вам не нравится? О! Пришёл в голову ещё один вариант: может, "(не)доделать"?

Comment: Тёмыч, правь! А я тут маленький ответик изобразила!

Comment: Правильно, вариант "не( )доделать" затрагивает вопрос о необходимости пробела, но рассматривает только вариант с НЕ (раздельным или слитным). Так что это не годится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оба варианта вполне приемлемы.

У слитной и раздельной форм написания глагола есть незначительные смысловые нюансы.

[Орфографический словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

> недоделать (сделать меньше нужного), но: не доделать (ещё не доделал
>   начатого)

См. также:

> Следует различать глаголы с приставкой недо- (придает глаголу значение
>   неполноты, недостаточности действия и по значению часто антонимична
>   приставке пере-): недоедать, недосыпать, недосмотреть, недослышать,
>   недоучесть, недобрать баллов, недоварить картофель; недовернуть гайку,
>   недовесить масла; недовыполнить план; недоглядеть за ребёнком;
>   недогрузить вагон; недооценить свои возможности; недополучить часть
>   товара и созвучные им глаголы с приставкой до-, которой предшествует
>   отрицание не (в сочетании с частицей глагол обозначает, что действие
>   не доведено до конца): не досмотреть спектакль до конца (‘не окончить
>   смотреть’); дети часто не доедали суп; никогда не доплачивали.

**[источник](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3919)**

Comment: Некоторые словари даже этих смысловых нюансов не улавливают. Похоже, что всегда допустимы оба варианта, только интонация в них будет разной.

Comment: А я чую (как мне кажется) разницу: *мастер не доделал укладку плитки* (хромой по смыслу пример, но формально подходит); а вот, из примеров в цитате: ***не досмотреть спектакль до конца - недосмотреть спектакль, дети часто не доедали суп - дети часто недоедали*** (голодали).

Comment: Я говорил только о "доделать", но Вы правы — в Вашем примере есть разница (хотя "не доделал укладку" звучит и правда не очень). А вот если сказать: "мастер недоделал работу по укладке плитки", она куда-то исчезает, мне кажется :)

Comment: Ой, это ж весьма скользкое правило...

Comment: Я бы всё же сказал: *мастер не доделал работу по укладке плитки*, хотя как у Вас, конечно, тоже можно (это к grizzly).

Comment: Будут ли те же правила действовать если заменить "чем" на "а"?

Comment: Имхо, при союзе *а* будет писаться слитно. (Я о двух примерах из пояснений к вопросу.)

Comment: Ой, поздно заметила ошибку в своём последнем комменте: "Лучше доделать, ***а не*** недоделать". Второй пример из пояснений автора просто невозможен с союзом *а*.